# My floating action button is not displayed properly...?

Tags: android, floating-action-button, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomappbar

I am using **TAB LAYOUT** with **View Pager** and a **BOTTOM APP BAR** with a Floating Action Button for Bottom Navigation but i think my floating action button is being displayed under view pager so its looking like its being cut from above....please help me fix this

Here is my XML Code....

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_main_bg"
    tools:context=".home.HomeActivity">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
            android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bottom_navigation_bg"
            app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="0dp"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/color_primary"
            />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/color_primary"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_plus"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomAppBar"
            android:contentDescription="@string/add_item_to_this_destination" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/color_primary"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/color_secondary"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/color_secondary"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/color_secondary" />

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/view_pager_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/coordinator_layout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tab_layout">

    </androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and here is what it looks like

[enter image description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8ZWu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because of CoordinatorLayout

Solution 1:
Add

```
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:clipChildren="false"
```

in CoordinatorLayout

Solution 2:
Make CoordinatorLayout as parent layout and put all child layout in it.

Solution 3:

In view_pager_2
add

```
            android:layout_marginBottom="?actionBarSize"
```

Solution 4:
Add this line to your fab

```
android:elevation="10dp"
```

Comment: yeahh..i know about solution2 you mentioned above but i was trying to make this work in Constraint layout

Comment: yeahh the solution 2 of yours works completly

Comment: Glad it helped. Please accept it as an answer.

Comment: @AnkitVerma I have added one more solution. Please check it too.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code to your BootomAppBar tag:

```
    app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
    app:fabCradleMargin="8dp"
```

So it will become:

```
 <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_navigation_bg"
        app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="0dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/color_primary"
        app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
        app:fabCradleMargin="8dp"
        />
```